# ChartJS GridLine Dynamically

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image: ![enter image description here]

I am getting output like this

I need TickLine dynamically according to our data, in chartJS
We are using tickMarkLength,so according to that it is giving all lines, but we need only start & end line.

gridLines: {
   drawOnChartArea: false, 
   tickMarkLength: 15,
}

I am expecting output like this

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hamalainen/6c0L1yva/3/

take refrence from this one

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code on the jsfiddle, changing

```js
gridLines: { drawOnChartArea: false }
```

to

```js
gridLines: false
```

does it. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: if i do gridLines: false then grid line hide but i need grid line also with labels